networkx graph get groups of linked/connected values
I've got such data
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6), (7)])

As you can see 1 is connected with 2 (edge 1, 2) and 1 is connected with 3.
This means that 2 is connected with 3 via 2.
So I'd like to get 3 arrays:
First - [1,2,3,4], second - [5,6], because 5 and 6 does not connect with rest values
and third array [7]
I expect getting arrays with connected values between each other.

You find to find the connected_components:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6), (7)])

out = list(nx.connected_components(G))

And for a DiGraph, nx.weakly_connected_components:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6), (7)])

out = list(nx.weakly_connected_components(G))

Output:
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7}]

Graph:


cool. Do you know what this error means?
raise nx.NetworkXNotImplemented(errmsg)
networkx.exception.NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for directed type

OOO...made it. Thanks.
Do you know how to pass EDGE with one value?
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6), (7)])
Ive got error
File "/opt/isu/home/yakimets-ei/heryaks.py", line 11, in 
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6), (7)])
File "/opt/isu/home/yakimets-ei/env312/lib/python3.12/site-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 1031, in add_edges_from
ne = len(e)
^^^^^^

Yes, for a DiGraph you would need nx.weakly_connected_components
